# Can I get likes by specific user using Instagram API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Can I get likes by specific user using Instagram API? I saw this in Windows Phone app, but I can't find it in API docs.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you can't.

This feature is only available on the Instagram app following [this steps](https://help.instagram.com/367550509992787)

> To view the 300 most-recent posts you've liked, go to your account
>   settings in the app and then tap Posts You've Liked. You won't be able
>   to view posts you've liked on the web.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand this correctly, you wish to get the most recently liked photos of a particular user.

This can be done using the Instagram API - but only when that particular user has authenticated your app.

You can use the following endpoint:

> GET /users/self/media/liked

Here the API call would be :

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

This will give you the list of recent media liked by the owner of the ACCESS-TOKEN.

More details on the Instagram API here :

> https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_feed_liked

Comment: Not anymore i guess. I got {"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "APINotAllowedError", "error_message": "This endpoint has been retired"}}

Comment: Any work around for this? Any little help would be much much appreciated! Thanks :)